# Glass Zener Diode Help

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, identification, zener

I'm not sure what type of zener diode this is. What I can tell is that it is either w15 or 315. I have 2 photos of the part in question. I have found that the one in question is shorted.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It may be easier to figure it out if you can analyze the circuit you took it out of. Trace it out and see what's connected where, and it may be that the zener voltage needed becomes obvious.

Comment: Not to be flippant but....   Are you sure this is a Zener diode?   You can't tell just by looking at it even if it looks like other zener's you've seen.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a 15V zener diode similar to HZ15-3L, but it would be better to trace out the circuit. Putting a higher voltage than original zener diode in a circuit could cause damage.